# Transaction still autocommit after throw error in GraphQL+Sequelize+CLS

Tags: postgresql, transactions, sequelize.js, graphql

I am wondering if there is any part in the coding that I did it wrong. 
I am trying to do a series of function and checking, and if there are some condition not met, I want to rollback the transaction.

I am refering to the reference at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822981/using-transaction-in-sequelize-for-postgres/34827862#34827862)

My transaction still get committed after throwing new error.

Here is my sample coding.

```
//db.js
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import Cls from 'continuation-local-storage';
Sequelize.cls = Cls.createNamespace('db');
const Conn = new Sequelize(
    'relay',
    'postgres',
    'tec832',
    {
    dialect: 'postgres',
        host: 'localhost'
    }
);
module.exports.Db = Conn;
```

in schema.js I have

```
Db.transaction({autocommit: false}).then(()=>{
    args = {vcTitle: {$ilike: `Sample title by Nick`}};
    return testDelPostPromiseNoTran(args).then(obResult => {
        throw new Error("Wrong account type");
    })
});

function testDelPostPromiseNoTran(args){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(delDataNoTran('Post', args));
    });
}

//I am trying to do a standard delete
function delDataNoTran(vcTbName, args){
    return Db.models[vcTbName].destroy({where: args})
    .then(result =>{
        if(result > 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    })
    .error(obStatus =>{
        return false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few issues with your code:

```
Db.transaction({autocommit: false}).then(()=>{
    args = {vcTitle: {$ilike: `Sample title by Nick`}};
    return testDelPostPromiseNoTran(args).then(obResult => {
        throw new Error("Wrong account type");
    })
});
```

Should be...

```
Db.transaction(()=>{
    args = {vcTitle: {$ilike: `Sample title by Nick`}};
    return testDelPostPromiseNoTran(args).then(obResult => {
        throw new Error("Wrong account type");
    })
});
```

You should pass a function to `Db.transaction`. Putting it inside of the `.then()` block means it runs *after* the transaction, and therefore isn't wrapped inside of a transaction. This is your main issue.

```
function testDelPostPromiseNoTran(args){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(delDataNoTran('Post', args));
    });
}
```

... return a promise that always resolves.  This is redundant, since `delDataNoTran` already returns a promise -- there's no reason to wrap it in another promise.

```
args = {vcTitle: {$ilike: `Sample title by Nick`}};
```

"ilike" should be "iLike" (case sensitive.)

I'd recommend spending some time reading the [Sequelize docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/).